# Google Cloud Messaging SSL error peer not authenticated

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have an issue regarding GCM. When my server app tries to send a message to GCM, it sometimes throws an error:

```
16-01-20 18:13:47,993 ERROR [com.chopper.ivolley.server.association.gcm.GcmNoticifationClient] (pool-5-thread-2) GCM returned an error: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287) [resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407) [resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:450) [resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation$5.call(ClientInvocation.java:513) [resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_65]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283) [resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
... 7 more
```

I imported the certificate from android.googleapis.com in my TrustStore and my app uses it, because i can also see log messages with successful m

I have no idea why this happens only from time to time. Could anybody help?